# Passing non serializable object between screens in react native

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native-navigation

I am working on ble related app. I am supposed to persist ble connection with device while navigating in app. I tried passing deviceObject which i am getting from ble connection using react-native-navigation passProps functionality, but it is not working for non-serializable object.

I am using 'react-native-ble-plx' library for ble connection.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: are you using Redux/Saga lib for managing app state ??

Comment: yes.. i am using redux  @tahirmahmood

Comment: then it will good just store your connected device in redux store..it 'll help you a lot .. then you can get it in all of your app

Comment: Thanks... @tahirmahmood
It is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per suggested by @tahirmanmood, best possible solution is to store your connected device in redux store.. so you can use it anywhere in your app later.